# How do I snoop on another processes memory from .Net?

Tags: .net, memory-management, interprocess

I'd like to attach to another process from a .Net console app and explore the data area. Specifically I would like to attach to the 'Spider Solitaire' app in Windows Vista as I am interested in seeing if the cards it deals out are solveable in all situations.

Is this possible and if so which APIs should I be looking at?

This is a 'just for fun' project so I can expand my knowledge.

Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use the win32 `ReadProcessMemory` API - there's nothing built-in.
See [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadProcessMemory.html) for information on how to do this using P/Invoke.
Also, check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/minememoryreader.aspx) sample.